# What does the infinitive "to call" work in this sentence?

Tags: infinitives

"I tried to call but the line was busy." Is the infinitive "to call"in this sentence used as noun,adverb or adjective?

Comment: I'm copy pasting the answer to your question about "to fly":  *None of the above, "To call" is an infinitive verb. **It's not a noun, adverb or adjective**.*      Infinitives are, by definition, verbs.   This is a catentive construction.

Comment: Yes, it is an infinitive but here it works  either as a noun or  an adverb

Comment: It doesn't "work as a noun or adverb" (which is impossible anyway)". James is right: "to call" is an infinitival clause functioning as a catenative complement of "tried".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What work does the infinitive " to fly " do?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/302526/what-work-does-the-infinitive-to-fly-do)

Comment: I agree with James K.  Actually though, this is different from the "to fly" example.  There, I could understand how the phrase "to fly" might be understood as having a quasi-adverbial role (even if today the term "adjunct" is preferred by linguists).  Here, I find it difficult to see how "to call" could be understood other than as a verb. Questions for the OP: (1) Why are you convinced it works as a noun or adverb? (2) Even if it did, why would you need to know which one it worked as? (3) How does your course guide or syllabus define "adverb" and "noun" etc? Can you use those definitions?

Comment: Some resources (especially those aimed at ESLs) consider such verbs  as objects and thus nouns. But this really makes little sense. Noun is a word category (part of speech), just as adverb and adjective etc. are. "Call" is clearly a verb since it denotes an action: the meaning here is "I endeavoured to call but the line was busy".

Comment: @DanielRoseman The link you provide is potentially misleading since it might imply that "to fly" has the same function as "to call", which it doesn't. The infinitival clause "to call" is functioning as a complement of "tried", while the infinitival "to fly" is functioning as a purpose adjunct.

Comment: There is a topic in our course book about uses of infinitive as a noun, an adjective and an adverb. These are examples  given to students for identification of infinitive working as noun, adverb or adjective. I am confused about "to call" infinitive.

Comment: @Rafiullah you need to quote the source and then **quote the relevant paragraph** (if it's not in English use Google translator, which is better than nothibg)  in the book that says an infinitive can be used as a noun, adverb or adjective.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work as a noun, adjective, or an adverb. It is a verb.  It is a short non-finite clause and it is the catenative complement of the verb "tried".